# How to stop mouseover and mouseout function after a click event

Tags: javascript, video, click, mouseover, mouseout

I have been trying to stop a mouseover and mouseout function after a click event but it does not work:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach(function(x){
        x.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
            video = this.querySelector('video');
            if (video.muted == true) {
                video.muted = false;
            } else {
                video.muted = true;}
        }, false)
        x.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
            this.querySelector('video').muted = true;
              }, false)
        x.addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.off('mouseover').;
        })
```

What i'm trying is to play the video with sound after a click, but instead, it continues with the mouseover effect.

Thank you! and sorry for bad english

Comment: `NodeList.forEach()` isn't [available on all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility) and `this` is a regular DOM node and not a jQuery object, hence there is no `.off()` method (which the browser should tell you in his console). Look for the counterpart of [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 1):

Use `removeEventListener` to remove attached event handler

```
function mouseoverfunc() {
            video = this.querySelector('video');
            if (video.muted == true) {
                video.muted = false;
            } else {
                video.muted = true;}
        }
document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach(function(x){
        x.addEventListener("mouseover",mouseoverfunc, false) 
        x.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
            this.querySelector('video').muted = true;
              }, false)
        x.addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.removeEventListener('mouseover',mouseoverfunc);
        })
```